# Xslt choose while condition is not working for me. Not going to otherwise block

Tags: xml, xslt

Respected Sir,

My Sample input is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Information>
            <jsonObject>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>1</_JsonReader_PS_id>
                <Guid>1958ac1d-7176-46c1-b767-b871d7ddb0a8</Guid>
                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Children>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_id>2</_JsonReader_PS_id>                    
                    <Items>                     
                        <DefinitionId>
                            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                            <Value>108</Value>
                        </DefinitionId>                     
                    </Items>
                </Children>
                <Children>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_id>4</_JsonReader_PS_id>                    
                    <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                    <Children>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_id>5</_JsonReader_PS_id>                        
                        <Items>                         
                            <DefinitionId>
                                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                                <Value>108</Value>
                            </DefinitionId>                         
                        </Items>
                    </Children>                 
                    <Items>                     
                        <DefinitionId>
                            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                            <Value>108</Value>
                        </DefinitionId>                     
                    </Items>
                </Children>
                <Children>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_id>29</_JsonReader_PS_id>                   
                    <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                    <Items>
                        <DefinitionId>
                            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                            <Value>108</Value>
                        </DefinitionId>
                    </Items>
                </Children>
                <Items>                 
                    <DefinitionId>
                        <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                        <Value>108</Value>
                    </DefinitionId>                 
                    <Id>
                        <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                        <Value>92</Value>
                    </Id>                   
                </Items>
            </jsonObject>
            <jsonObject>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>79.0</_JsonReader_PS_id>
                <?xml-multiple  Children?>              
                <Items>
                    <DefinitionId>
                        <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                        <Value>108</Value>
                    </DefinitionId>                 
                </Items>
                <Instance>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_id>179.0</_JsonReader_PS_id>
                    <Items>                     
                        <DefinitionId>
                            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                            <Value>108</Value>
                            <Original>108</Original>
                        </DefinitionId>                     
                        <Id>
                            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                            <Value>96</Value>
                        </Id>                       
                    </Items>
                </Instance>
            </jsonObject>
        </Information>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There are two "jsonObject" inside Information tag . I a running for-each on "jsonObject" and trying to check the "Items/Id/Value" inside jsonObject tag.
If "Items/Id/Value" is not equal 92 or if "Items/Id/Value" is not present in jsonObject. Then I want to pick that jsonObject , and add it to the Children array of jsonObject with id 92.
Here is what I have tried.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:variable name="firstId" select="92" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <jsonObject>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </jsonObject>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="Information">
            <xsl:for-each select="jsonObject">            
               <firstId><xsl:value-of select="$firstId"/></firstId>
               <id><xsl:value-of select="Items/Id/Value"/></id>
                <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="//Items/Id/Value = $firstId">
                       <test1>test1</test1>
                       <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Children>
                            <test2>test2</test2>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                        </Children>
                     </xsl:otherwise>
                 </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xslt is not going inside "otherwise" block, of choose, even when "id" is not present in jsonObject.
Here is expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsonObject>

    <firstId>92</firstId>
    <id>92</id>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <_JsonReader_PS_id xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">1</_JsonReader_PS_id>
    <Guid xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">1958ac1d-7176-46c1-b767-b871d7ddb0a8</Guid>
    <Children xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <_JsonReader_PS_id>2</_JsonReader_PS_id>                    
        <Items>                     
            <DefinitionId>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>108</Value>
            </DefinitionId>                     
        </Items>
    </Children>
    <Children xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <_JsonReader_PS_id>4</_JsonReader_PS_id>                    
        <?xml-multiple Children?>
        <Children>
            <_JsonReader_PS_id>5</_JsonReader_PS_id>                        
            <Items>                         
                <DefinitionId>
                    <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                    <Value>108</Value>
                </DefinitionId>                         
            </Items>
        </Children>                 
        <Items>                     
            <DefinitionId>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>108</Value>
            </DefinitionId>                     
        </Items>
    </Children>
    <Children xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <_JsonReader_PS_id>29</_JsonReader_PS_id>                   
        <?xml-multiple Children?>
        <Items>
            <DefinitionId>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>108</Value>
            </DefinitionId>
        </Items>
    </Children>
    <Children xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <_JsonReader_PS_id xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">79.0</_JsonReader_PS_id>
        <Items xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <DefinitionId>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>108</Value>
            </DefinitionId>                 
        </Items>
        <Instance xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <_JsonReader_PS_id>179.0</_JsonReader_PS_id>
            <Items>                     
                <DefinitionId>
                    <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                    <Value>108</Value>
                    <Original>108</Original>
                </DefinitionId>                     
                <Id>
                    <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                    <Value>96</Value>
                </Id>                       
            </Items>
        </Instance>
    </Children>
    <Items xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">                   
        <DefinitionId>
            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
            <Value>108</Value>
        </DefinitionId>                 
        <Id>
            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
            <Value>92</Value>
        </Id>                   
    </Items>
    <firstId>92</firstId>
    <id/>
    <test1>test1</test1>        

</jsonObject>
```

In the output , one more child element should be added , which is the jsonObject for which "Items/Id/Value" is not present or not equal to 92.
 I do not understand why the otherwise condition is not working , even when the id is not present for that jsonObject.
 Please guide.

My Current output is below :

You can observe clearly, , that in second iteration of foreach xslt recognizes "Items/Id/Value" is not present.
Observe the tags 92 and   . But still it does not go into otherwise of this condition test="//Items/Id/Value = $firstId" .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsonObject>

    <firstId>92</firstId>
    <id>92</id>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <_JsonReader_PS_id xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">1</_JsonReader_PS_id>
    <Guid xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">1958ac1d-7176-46c1-b767-b871d7ddb0a8</Guid>
    <Children xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <_JsonReader_PS_id>2</_JsonReader_PS_id>                    
        <Items>                     
            <DefinitionId>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>108</Value>
            </DefinitionId>                     
        </Items>
    </Children>
    <Children xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <_JsonReader_PS_id>4</_JsonReader_PS_id>                    
        <?xml-multiple Children?>
        <Children>
            <_JsonReader_PS_id>5</_JsonReader_PS_id>                        
            <Items>                         
                <DefinitionId>
                    <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                    <Value>108</Value>
                </DefinitionId>                         
            </Items>
        </Children>                 
        <Items>                     
            <DefinitionId>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>108</Value>
            </DefinitionId>                     
        </Items>
    </Children>
    <Children xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <_JsonReader_PS_id>29</_JsonReader_PS_id>                   
        <?xml-multiple Children?>
        <Items>
            <DefinitionId>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>108</Value>
            </DefinitionId>
        </Items>
    </Children>
    <Items xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">                   
        <DefinitionId>
            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
            <Value>108</Value>
        </DefinitionId>                 
        <Id>
            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
            <Value>92</Value>
        </Id>                   
    </Items>
    <firstId>92</firstId>
    <id/>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <_JsonReader_PS_id xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">79.0</_JsonReader_PS_id>
    <Items xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <DefinitionId>
            <Type>System.Int32</Type>
            <Value>108</Value>
        </DefinitionId>                 
    </Items>
    <Instance xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <_JsonReader_PS_id>179.0</_JsonReader_PS_id>
        <Items>                     
            <DefinitionId>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>108</Value>
                <Original>108</Original>
            </DefinitionId>                     
            <Id>
                <Type>System.Int32</Type>
                <Value>96</Value>
            </Id>                       
        </Items>
    </Instance>

</jsonObject>
```

---

After this line whatever I am mentioning is about the issues I am facing after making the changes suggested below. Continuing here as I cannot add attachemnts and screenshots in comments:

[image]

The requirement is that the newly generated Children element in otherwise condition ,should be added to the Children array of jsonObject with id 92.
Please observe the tag `<?xml-multiple  Children?>` above children element in input xml. Needs to be added to that array. 
Current situation is, Whenever I convert this to json output, the last Children  tag only prevails over existing Children array.

Actually the real expected output is when I convert it to json . the new Children should be added to the existing list of children for jsonObject with id 92.

I think the last children block have to be added exactly at the same position it is there in expected output so that it remains as newly added element to existing Children element of jsonObject with id 92.But not sure if thats the actual issue and how to solve it.
 Please guide.

[image]

Comment: My Current output is :

Answer (score 2):

Your test condition `test="//Items/Id/Value = $firstId"` is testing to see if there is **any** `Items` with an `Id` with a `Value` of `$firstId`. It is not testing if the current `Items` `Id` has a `Value` equal to `$firstId`.

Removing the two slashes will scope the test per item instead of throughout the XML and this will match what you are outputting in your id tag.

`test="Items/Id/Value = $firstId"`

Comment: Thanks sir ,
The otherwise condition now worked .
But the new Children I added  in otherwise condition is not added to Children array of jsonObject with id 92. But it added as a single element separately. I have added a screenshot of the output after converting it to json. The requirement is that the new generated Children element should be added to the Children array of jsonObject with id 92
Please guide.

Comment: I  think it may be due to the new Children element getting added at last of jsonObject with id 92 and not exactly  at the place where it is in the expected output I shared. i.e. just after the existing Children of jsonObject with id 92. Please Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following row in your XSLT script:

```
<xsl:when test="//Items/Id/Value = $firstId">
```

Note that the `test` condition starts with `//`, i.e. you check
whether at least one `Items/Id/Value` element in the **whole source XML**
equals `$firstId`. In your case this is always *true*.

I think, you should remove `//` chars, i.e. check each `Items/Id/Value`
in the **current** `jsonObject`.

In the first `jsonObject` there is **one** such *Value*, in the second -
**none**, so you should check **just this** (internal) object,
not looking for `Items/Id/Value` elements in the whole document.

### Edit

What you presented as JSON screenshot is apparently a result of some further
processing of XSLT output.

Look at the first source *jsonObject* (id = 92).
It contains **three** *Children* tags and the second of
them contains one more (internal) *Children* tag.

And now compare it with the first part of your screenshot
(up to *id = 96*).
It contains **only one** *Children* tag, so probably
your software somehow "joins" *Children* tags from XSLT
result (for the first *jsonObject*).

My assumption that what you presented is not any direct result of XSLT script
supports also the fact, that the screenshot contains *Lookups* and *PrimaryKey*
tags, which are not present in your source XML.

So probably you should inspect what your software further does with the XSLT
output, instead of looking errors in the XSLT script.

Note also a weird difference between *when* and *otherwise* branches.

*When* branch contains "direct" `<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>`, whereas
*otherwise* branch "envelopes" `<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>` in a `<Children>`
tag.

I think, you should not create this "additional" `<Children>` tag
in *otherwise* branch, as you wrote in your second comment.

Comment: Thanks sir ,
The otherwise condition now worked .
But the new Children I added  in otherwise condition is not added to Children array of jsonObject with id 92.But it is getting added as a single element separately.
I have added a screenshot of the current output after converting it to json. 
The requirement is that the newly generated Children element should be added to the Children array of jsonObject with id 92.
Please guide.

Comment: I  think it may be due to the new Children element getting added at last of jsonObject with id 92 and not exactly  at the place where it is in the expected output I shared. i.e. just after the existing Children of jsonObject with id 92. Please Guide.